# How to call function

Tags: python, function, recursion, time, pyqt5

I have to combo box ; ComboBox1 and ComboBox2. 
I would like to retrieve value from both combo box to get a result of whether it is ' breakfast' or 'lunch'

Combobox1 will fetch the data of hours e.g 07,08,09,10
combobox2 will fetch the data of mins, e.g 30,59,etc

The intended outcome is for the system to fetch these two values and identify if it is breakfast or lunch. One example is 07 and 59 which makes it 7:59am and it is breakfast.

I have two function which prints the value selected by the user seperately... I would like to print " You have selected ' 07:59'"
Also, i would like the system to identify that it is breakfast, so i can open the breakfast page when i proceed to the next page.

```
        page.comboBox.addItems(selecthour)
    page.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onComboActivated)

    page.comboBox.setGeometry(150,30,105,40)

    page.comboBox2.addItems(selectmin)
    page.comboBox2.activated[str].connect(self.onCombo2Activated)
    page.comboBox2.setGeometry(280,30,105,40)


    def onCombo2Activated(self, text):
        print("choose time: {}".format(text))
        if 800<= int(text) <= 1200:
            print('Hello')
```

Comment: What's the threshold between breakfast and lunch? If it's exactly on an hour, then the minutes doesn't matter at all, and changing it will never change the meal. Otherwise, you probably need to rewrite your functions to either save the new value to a variable, or to poll the other combobox (the one that has not just changed), to see its current value so you can tell what meal is appropriate.

Comment: @Blckknght breakfast time is around 730am to 1130am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Main(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        selecthour = [ '{:>02}'.format(i) for i in range(6, 23)]
        selectmin  = [ '{:>02}'.format(i) for i in range(0, 60)]

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.addItems(selecthour)
        self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(lambda ch, c='hour': self.onComboActivated(ch, c))
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(150, 30, 105, 40)

        self.comboBox2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox2.addItems(selectmin)
        self.comboBox2.activated[str].connect(lambda ch, c='min': self.onComboActivated(ch, c))
        self.comboBox2.setGeometry(280,30,105,40)        

    def onComboActivated(self, text, c):
        print("\nchoose  time: {} - {}".format(text, c))

        print("current time: {}:{}".format(self.comboBox.currentText(), self.comboBox2.currentText()))

        text = "{}{}".format(self.comboBox.currentText(), self.comboBox2.currentText())
        if '0730' <= text <= '1130': 
            print('Hello, breakfast') 
        elif '1131' <= text <= '1600': 
            print('Hello, lunch') 
        elif '1601' <= text <= '1900': 
            print('Hello, supper') 
        else: 
            print('It’s harmful to eat at this time.')          


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me out! How I would need my breakfast timing to start from 7:30 to 11:30. How do I print breakfast for the selected timing? @S.Nick

Comment: @BANGTANSOPE  `if '0730' <= text <= '1130':`

Comment: I would like to use this code for QDialog, but it doesn't work, what do I have to edit to make it work? @S. Nick

Comment: @BANGTANSOPE  I inserted your time intervals and inherited from `QDialog`.
Leading zero is necessarily `'0730'`.